# how to use property set in sonarqube for the sonar-scanner

Tags: sonarqube

I'm creating a plugin for SonarQube and have defined some properties. I've used the type 'property set' as below:

```
PropertyDefinition.builder(PROJECT_SET)
.index(1)
.name("Project Definition")
.description("Define the project(s) to gather data from")
.type(PropertyType.PROPERTY_SET)
.fields(
        PropertyFieldDefinition.build(PROJECT_URL)
                .name("Project URL")
                .description("Specify the project URL in the format: http(s)://<hostname>:<port>")
                .type(PropertyType.STRING).build(),
        PropertyFieldDefinition.build(PROJECT_NAME)
                .name("Project Name")
                .description("Specify the project name")
                .type(PropertyType.STRING).build(),
        PropertyFieldDefinition.build(PROJECT_QUERY)
                .name("Project Search Query")
                .description("Specify the search query to retrieve data from the project")
                .type(PropertyType.STRING).build(),
        PropertyFieldDefinition.build(PROJECT_VIEW)
                .name("Project View")
                .description("(OPTIONAL): Specify a view to apply to the query")
                .type(PropertyType.STRING).build()
)
.category(MAIN_MENU)
.onlyOnQualifiers(Qualifiers.PROJECT)
.build()
```

This works fine when setting the properties from the project web page, but I cant work out how to do this from the sonar-project.properties file. I see from the code the keys come out as:

```
PROJECT_SET.1.PROJECT_URL
```

e.g. myplugin.1.url=http://someurl:8080

But when I use this it doesnt work. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Solved, its the same syntax as a multi-module so:

```
PROJECT_SET=1,2
PROJECT_SET.1.PROJECT_URL=<url>
PROJECT_SET.2.PROJECT_URL=<url>
...
```